# Use of base constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

I'm having a problem with one of the C# applications I'm maintaining.  I see something I don't understand so I would like to ask for clarification.  It may or may not be related to the problem I'm having.

```
class C2iModel
{
    public C2iModel() { //blah }
}

class EplrsModel : C2iModel
{
    public EplrsModel() : base() { //blah }
}
```

My understanding is when a child constructor is invoked, the parent constructor is automatically invoked.

My question is does it make any difference whether the explicit call to base constructor is present in the `EplrsModel` constructor?

Comment: The parent types [*default* constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) is used if there is no `base` specified, and being the one with no parameters, is the same constructor that `base()` uses. From the link "In a derived class, if a base-class constructor is not called explicitly by using the base keyword, the default constructor, if there is one, is called implicitly. This means that the following constructor declarations [with and without `base()`] are effectively the same".

Comment: In this particular case (no ctor parameters) it makes absolutely no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, calling the base constructor is redundant. You only need to explicitly specify that for constructors when you're passing in arguments. Example:

```
class Base {

  public Base(string type) { ... }
}

class Extend : Base {

  public Extend(string type, string name) : base(type) { ... }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that bit of code is redundant.

Comment: Are you certain that the parent constructor isn't invoked twice by the EplrsModel constructor?

Comment: It is not invoked twice. Creating a single instace of EplrsModel means that the constructors are only called once.

Comment: No constructors are invoked twice, and for each class, at least one constructor is invoked, you can be sure of that.

Comment: @ThomasNguyen: Yes, I'm sure.